# Hive LEFT SEMI JOIN for 'NOT EXISTS'

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, semi-join

I have two tables with a single key column. Keys in table a are subset of all keys in table b. I need to select keys from table b that are NOT in table a.

Here is a citation from Hive manual:
"LEFT SEMI JOIN implements the uncorrelated IN/EXISTS subquery semantics in an efficient way. As of Hive 0.13 the IN/NOT IN/EXISTS/NOT EXISTS operators are supported using subqueries so most of these JOINs don't have to be performed manually anymore. The restrictions of using LEFT SEMI JOIN is that the **right-hand-side table should only be referenced in the join condition (ON-clause), but not in WHERE- or SELECT-clauses etc.**"

They use this example for illustration:

```
    SELECT a.key, a.value FROM a WHERE a.key IN (SELECT b.key FROM B);
```

Is equivalent to

```
    SELECT a.key, a.val FROM a LEFT SEMI JOIN b ON (a.key = b.key);
```

However, what I need to do is first example with 'NOT IN;. Unfortunately this syntax is not supported in Hive 0.13. It's for illustration only:

```
    SELECT a.key, a.value FROM a WHERE a.key NOT IN (SELECT b.key FROM B);
```

I searched this site for recommendations, and saw this example:

```
    SELECT a.key FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.key = b.key WHERE b.key IS NULL;
```

It does not work as expected. When I join a.key NOT in b and a.key IN b, I don't get the original a this way. Maybe that is because this query cannot do the trick, note bold text - b.key should not appear in WHERE.

What should I do then? Any other trick? Thanks!

P.S. I cannot share any real data; it's a pretty simple example, where keys in a are all included in b and a is a subset of b.

Comment: In all databases that I know of, the `not in` and `left join` with `is null` are functionally equivalent, assuming the comparison values are not `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how that can help. What is the solution query?

Comment: . . Your last query should be functionally equivalent to the `not in` version (assuming no `NULL` values).  Perhaps you can edit your question and explain how it is not doing what you expect.  I understand how the queries work.  I don't understand what you expect.

Comment: I explained how its not working on large data set, though on simple data it works correctly. The question was: "Is there any other way of doing what I need?"

Comment: Here is an alternative solution. SELECT key FROM (SELECT a.key, b1.marker FROM (SELECT key, COUNT(2) AS marker FROM b GROUP BY key) b1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN a ON b1.key = a.key) t WHERE marker IS NULL;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854649/hive-use-not-exists-in-using-semi-join?lq=1

Answer (score 8):

If you want results from table b, perhaps you can do the following instead?

```
  SELECT b.key FROM b LEFT OUTER JOIN a ON b.key = a.key WHERE a.key IS NULL;
```

Comment: I want results from table a, not in b, so I cannot select anything from table b. Consider table b is a blacklist of IPs. I want to select everything from table a including IP, where not blacklisted. Hence, the join is on IP as a key column.

Comment: @mel your question clearly says that you need to select keys from table b which are not in table a. OKK77's answer is potentially the right answer. Please accept!

Answer (score 5):

Or you can try

```
SELECT a.key FROM a LEFT ANTI JOIN b ON a.key = b.key
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your issue should be

```
SELECT a.key FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.key = b.key WHERE b.key IS NULL;
```

This means, bring all the keys from a, irrespective of whether there is a match in b or not. The where cause will filter those records, which are not available in b.

Answer (score 1):

I tried left semi join for IN function in cdh 5.7.0 with spark 1.6 version.

The semi left join gives wrong results, which is not similar to **IN function** in sub queries.